# Retrieve distinct backref instances from SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Given the following models:

```
class Foo(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = db.Column(
        "bar_id",
        db.Integer(),
        db.ForeignKey("bar.id"))
    baz_id = db.Column(
        "baz_id",
        db.Integer(),
        db.ForeignKey("baz.id"))
    bars = db.Relationship(
        "Bar",
        backref=backref("bar_foo", lazy="dynamic"))
    bazs = db.relationship(
        "Baz",
        backref=backref("baz_foo", lazy="dynamic"))

class Bar(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # some more columns

class Baz(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # some more columns

q = Bar.query.get(123).bar_foo
# .all() gives me several Foo instances
```

I'd like to retrieve the distinct Baz instances for the q result

Answer (score 0):

Take a set of the result returned by the query. The `object`s returned are *hashable* by default and therefore the `set` function can tell two Foo `object`s apart and will ensure what you get in `q` are actually distinct.